# Wordpress custom theme development: single-{post_type}-{slug}.php hierarchy explained

Tags: php, wordpress, theme-development

I am developing custom wordpress websites, the page hierarchy has been a hard concept for me to understand 100%.

I have a href

```
<a class="viewCar" id="15" href="/BWM/M4">........</a>
```

**In the wordpress backend:**

BMW is a page
M4 is a post

Now in my files, i have created a file called 
**single-{post_type}-{slug}.php**

When i click the href, the URL should be **[www.car.com/BWM/M4](http://www.car.com/BWM/M4)** but i get **[www.car.com/M4](http://www.car.com/M4)**

Secondly the page defaults to the index.php skipping all the other suggested pages from https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts are different from pages, You need to check the [page template documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files)

If you just have to customize one page then you can use the `page-{slug}.php` way otherwise I will suggest you to use [Custom page template option](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)